# Changing string in an m3u file with regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to make a change in an m3u file. The only thing I want to achieve is to replace what is in "tvg-name=" with "tvg-id="

Here is the sample of m3u:

```
#EXTINF:0 user-agent="Firefox/100.0" tvg-id="" tvg-name="TR I beIN MOVIES PREMIER HD 1080P (beIN)" tvg-logo="" group-title="--SINEMA KANALLARI--",TR I beIN MOVIES PREMIER HD 1080P (beIN)
http://xxxxxxx
#EXTINF:0 user-agent="Firefox/100.0" tvg-id="" tvg-name="TR I beIN MOVIES PREMIER 2 1080P (beIN)" tvg-logo="" group-title="--SINEMA KANALLARI--",TR I beIN MOVIES PREMIER 2 1080P (beIN)
http://xxxxxxx
#EXTINF:0 user-agent="Firefox/100.0" tvg-id="" tvg-name="TR I beIN MOVIES ACTION 1080P (beIN)" tvg-logo="" group-title="--SINEMA KANALLARI--",TR I beIN MOVIES ACTION 1080P (beIN)
http://xxxxxxx
```

I am not good at regex (not in python either, yet) but my code is below:

```
import re

line = open('z.m3u', "r", encoding='utf-8')
read_lines=line.read()
pattern=re.compile(r'tvg-id=(".*?").tvg-name=(".*?")')
matches=pattern.finditer(read_lines)

for match in matches:
    tvg_id=match.group(1)
    tvg_name=match.group(2)

    w=re.sub(tvg_id,tvg_name,read_lines)
    print(w)
    line.write(w)
```

However, I cannot get the file written with the changes. A help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need regex for the replacement, since you're replacing exact strings and not based on regex, which you used for capturing.

Change

`w=re.sub(tvg_id,tvg_name,read_lines)`

for

`w = read_lines.replace('tvg-name=' + tvg_name, 'tvg-name=' + tvg_id)`

and it may work.